# separating bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
   labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl"))

 data <- mtcars[which(mtcars$gear==3),]

 ggplot(data, aes(x = gear, y = vs, fill=cyl))+geom_point()+stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="bar",position="dodge",width=0.5)
```

Can I create ticks based on the variable in fill, so instead of a legend I get x axis tick labels called 4cyl and 6cyl?

Comment: In ggplot you can only have one variable on the `x`axis and you've already assigned the `gear` variable. Often people will use faceting in this case. Maybe try ` + facet_grid(~cyl)`

Comment: Alternatively you can use  `aes(x = interaction(gear, cyl), y = vs, fill=cyl)`, but facets will likely look better.

Comment: Actually, what I really wanted was: aes(x = gear, y = vs, fill=gear). Don't know how I couldn't see that before. Guess that's what you get from working late on fridays. Thanks for your help all the same!